# binomial glmm with distinct covariate values for random effects factor levels in R

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, count-data

I am dealing with the formulation of a model for ratios of countdata in R, using the command `glmer` from the `lme4` Package. As I am not advanced in the actual internal methodology, I'm trying to go for a more concepual view on my problem.

My experiment comprises three treatments onto pots with a constant number of sown plant seeds. 14 species where included in the experiment ; pots recieved a monospecific set of seeds. Pots with the same treatment-species-combinations were initially replicated in several blocks but for the analysis in question, I calculated a single median number of emerged seeds per treatment-species-combination. As a result, my data can be viewed as a [3 treatments * 14 plant species] - matrix with one response number of emerged seedlings per cell.

A straightforward analysis of factor effects and interactions could be formulated in pseudocode:

```
glm(cbind(emerged seedlings, "inactive" seeds) ~ treatment * species, family = "binomial")
```

I am particularly interested in interactions of species-specific numeric seed traits (let's say mean seed mass) with the treatment factor. With this in mind, I constructed another glm - basically a multiple regression style design:

```
glm(cbind(emerged seedlings, "inactive" seeds) ~ treatment * seedmass, family = "binomial")
```

In order to account for the fact, that there are three data points per species and the species identity of seeds can in itself have an influence onto the emergence probability of a seedling, which I am not explicitly interested in, I constructed a mixed model with "species" as a source of random intercept variation:

```
glmer(cbind(emerged seedlings, "inactive" seeds) ~ treatment * seedmass + (1|species), family = "binomial")
```

There are no convergence problems, model critique plots look ok as far as I am concerned and there seems to be only minor overdispersion.

Now to my problem:
Every distinct value of seed mass obviously coincides with one distinct level of the random intercepts factor. "species" could basically be viewed as a factorized version of "seed mass".
In my understanding, by accounting for a "species" random effect, all data variation explainable by seed mass would be shifted to the "random-part" of the model. I imagine it kind of like analyzing seed mass effects in the residuals of a partial factorial analysis with "species" as an explaining factor.

My results indicate that seedmass does not have a significant influence onto emergence numbers but highly significantly interacts with the treatment factor.
Now, I really don't trust these results because of obvious dependencies between the fixed term and the random component. On the other hand, I wouldn't dare just exclude "species identity" from the model because I think the assumption of independent sampling is violated.
Taking one step back, I might come to the conclusion that effects of "mere" species identity and of species-specific traits cannot be seperated statistically. But then, rephrasing my initial interest, I am interested in what part of the species effects and species-treatment-interactions could be attributed to species-specific numerical seed traits.

A similar, but not entirely redundant question was asked here:
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2009q3/002565.html

Firstly, the author adresses "singularities" in a fixed and a random effects factor, while I have a fixed numerical covariate. Secondly, because of its abstract nature, the answer doesn't help me in solving my problem.